# how to manage content using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

Can someone give me info about how to manage contents like post, in a website. Can I store post contents in mysql and retrieve them, or do I have to do something different.

I am making a website where user can post their articles. So to implement that can I use mysql as my database and php to process the information and show it on website.

One more thing I am confused about how to generate links to those articles dynamically, like
 http://www.example.com/first-article.php

http://www.example.com/second-article.php

So are these files like *first-article.php* going to be created in my website folder. If so isn't it going to create mess after some years, when you will be having like 10,000 post so that means 10,000 php files.

I don't want to use content management systems like joomla, drupal or wordpress. Please guide me how to implement those above mentioned.

Comment: The question is too broad and basically opinion based. I think you have to read the basic of PHP MySQL development and for the dynamic link read URL-rewrite of the web server. Google will be a much better place to ask this question.

Comment: I think for cms joomla is best.Just go http://www.joomla.org/download.html download it . install it .

Answer (score 2):

First you'll need to create a table to store all your data.

Let's do something like that to begin :

```
articles
--------
id_article (integer) (auto_increment) (primary key)
title (varchar 250)
author (varchar 250)
date (date)
content (text)
```

You can create this table easily in your favorite database management tool.

If you don't have any, I highly recommend [mysql workbench][1] which is awesome (You may consider using a good tool from the beginning, not that shitty phpMyAdmin...).

`id_article` is a number which will help you to identify your articles.
You don't have to set it, it starts from 1, and will auto increment.

Then let's focus on the php script.
I suggest 3 : `articles.php` to display all articles, `article_detail.php` to display one full article, and `article_edit.php` to edit an article.

Note that I won't give you php code otherwise you may not learn a lot. I'll just give you pseudo-code, let me know if you are stuck and need help.

```
//articles.php  //<---this is a comment
//first let's prepare a basic html page
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Article list</title>
    </head>
<body>
<h3>Articles list :</h3>
<ul>
<?php
//connect to mysql server + select database using [mysqli][2]
//execute the following query : "Select * from articles" with [mysqli_query][3]
//loop on your resultset using while and [mysqli_fetch_array()][4]
    //in your loop, echo the <li></li> that will populate your <ul>
    //Note, to create the links use : echo "<a href='./article_detail.php?id=".$row['id_article']."'>".$row['title']."</a>";
?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

There is our first script.
You can try it by manually creating some rows in the table `articles`

```
//article_detail.php
//Note that there isn't much new in there
//First your html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Article detail</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
//a new thing are the http variables.
//we will be using [$_GET][5]
$id_article = (int) $_GET['id_article']; //remember to cast your integers as int in order to prevent SQL Injection
//connect to the database.
//use mysqli_query to execute : "Select * from articles where id_article='$id_article'"
//use fetch_array() to get the row.
//display the row the way you want using html.
</html>
```

Once you have tested this, you can move on the final script.

This one will take an integer as `$_GET` parameter : 'id_article' (if there is no parameter then we will have to create a new article using mysql.
And it will also optionnaly take a `$POST` parameter with `title`, `author` and `content`.

```
//article_edit.php
<html><head><title>Edit an article</title></head>
<body>

<?
if(count($_POST)){
//POST request, get the parameters from it, and update the row using $_GET['id_article']
//remember to use htmlentities() and addslashes() on author, title and content, so your script is bullet-proof to XSS and SQL Injection
echo "<h3 style='color:green;text-align:center;'>Article updated!</h3>";
}
if(isset($_GET['id_article'])){
    //We are editing an existing article : gather its content for edition
}else{
    //New article, create an empty row, and select it.
}
//after this if statement you should have '$id_article' and an array '$article' which contains the article data

?>

<form method='post' action='./article_edit.php?id_article=<?=$id_article?>'>
Author : <input size='50' name='article_author' value='<?=$article['author']?>'/><br/>
Title  : <input size='100' name='article_title' value='<?=$article['title']?>'/><br/>
Content : <textarea name='article_content'><?=$article['content']?></textarea><br/>
<input type='submit' value='Send'/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

There you go.

A good php function, if I could name a friendly one, is [var_dump()][6], it basically shows you the content of variables. Very good tool.

What to do next ?

-Save the creation date of the article.

-Use include and centralize your common source code (eg : mysql_connect, html headers...)

-Add a login page, and authorize editing only to members.

-Install a text editor like tiny_mce for editing articles.

-...

Have fun.

1: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/

2: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

3: http://php.net/mysqli_query

4: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

5: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

6: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: Loic: Thanks a lot man, you have given me every bit of information to head start from here, thanks again, i got it, what i was looking for. you're awesome.

Comment: Oh stop that you, I'll blush.

Answer (score 0):

While i agree that the question is quite broad, perhaps a look at a PHP Framework like Laravel may help you http://laravel.com.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use php and mysql to implement your desired system.

What you can do is create a table in the mysql database for your posts like tbl_articles that holds all your data relating to an article such as its id, title, content, date, etc.
Next you can create a php page such as display_article.php that displays each article based on the id provided in the url. Then your url can be in the form http://example.com/display_article.php/first-article

This is just a suggestion. There can be other better methods to do it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

"I don't want to use content management systems like joomla, drupal or wordpress. Please guide me how to implement those above mentioned."

What you are describing is essentially writing your own CMS. You need to learn PHP and MySQL at a level higher that you have right now. "How to write my own CMS" is probably too large of a question for SO.

There's a few guides on the web that might be better suited for what you are doing. Try:

```
[http://css-tricks.com/php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms/][1]
[http://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/][2]
```

Please vote. =)

Comment: Another tutorial:

[http://www.frasq.org/en/manual/write-a-cms-in-php/controlling-actions][3]

Or, if Drupal and Wordpress are too big for your needs, you can download one of the already existing super lightweight CMSes: 

[http://www.queness.com/post/14579/6-lightweight-flexible-php-cms][4]

Comment: Thanks, I know php and mysql, will be giving more time to learn advanced php, Sorry i can't upvote because i don't have 15+ reputation

Comment: can you please mention particular topics on PHP and MySql which i should study to get to be able to create CMS for my own website

Comment: All three of the sites I mentioned are specific to PHP and MySQL for creating a CMS. Please upvote when you get a reputation. =)